# Objective-C autoreleasepool directive effect variables outside scope.

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

Let's say I've got c++ function combined with objective-c members.
The function gets `std::string` and convert it to `NSstring*`, and work with this variable before leaving...

Should i expect the `NSstring*` to be released at the end of `autoreleasepool` scope ?

```
void myclass::myfunc(context& ctx)
{ 
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        std::string path = ctx.getData().path;
        NSString *nsPath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()];
        ... (do something with nsString, Should it be released after leaving the scope ?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to. According to the rule you only need release the variable if you are increasing its retain count in one of the following ways:

1. Initializing via new or alloc/init.
2. Copying via copy.
3. Increasing the retain count via retain.

If you are getting a variable by any means but the above-mentioned ways, you don't own it, and hence you don't need to release it.

The string returned via `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()]` is autoreleased string. It will be released once the current runloop finishes. So you don't need to release it.

Comment: But `nsPath` is set according to `path.c_str()` using method  `NSString stringWithUTF8String` and i'm not sure if it's perform copy behind scene or not...

Comment: It returns autoreleased object of NSString. So again as per the rule, you don't need to release it.

Comment: ok thanks... perhaps do you know what's happen if the return value of the expression `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()]` is NULL.. does the ARC handle this situation as well ?

Comment: If its nil for some reason then there is no object. No object means no memory.

Comment: "It will automatically be released once your current function exits" - unfortunately this is *incorrect*. Under ARC the object will be released *either* when the current auto release pool is emptied, and the systems default pool is emptied at the end of each iteration of the run loop; *or* sooner if ARC determines this is possible, while this may be at the end of the current function it most definitely may not be.

Comment: @CRD Here I mean that exact thing that you mentioned. I just hide the details. According to ARC, anything that you don't create / copy / retain, you don't own. And when you don't own anything, you shouldn't worry about its retain count. They are supposed to be autoreleased and good only for your current use (i.e in the current function). If you are interesting in using it even after the current scope you can retain/copy it and you becomes the owner. Now its your responsibility to release it.

Comment: @HAK - There might be a language misunderstanding here. "(i.e in the current function)" - no, it can be used beyond the "current function", for example it can be passed to other functions or returned from the current one. The lifetime of the object is not tied directly to the "current function" but to the "current auto release pool". ARC is capable of optimising the lifetime but that is essentially invisible.

Comment: @CRD You are correct. I mentioned function to keep the things simple. But I think its misleading. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "The string returned via [NSString stringWithUTF8String:path.c_str()] is autoreleased string." There is no guarantee that it is autoreleased (i.e. that it ever goes into the autorelease pool) in ARC.

Comment: "If you are getting a variable by any means but the above-mentioned ways, you don't own it, and hence you don't need to release it." Just because you don't see a retain doesn't mean that ARC isn't retaining what you get from that call when you assign it to the local variable. But the programmer shouldn't be worried about retains and releases in ARC anyway.